# adding an <a> tag messes everything up

Tags: html, css

I want to add links for every box but whenever I try to add an "a" tag it messes everything up. What am I missing :-/ ? I have tried a lot of stuff and still can't figure out what wrong. Would appreciate your help.
Thanks 
This is how it is supposed to look
http://oi66.tinypic.com/iykcc5.jpg

https://jsfiddle.net/983wga5c/7/

**HTML**

```
<div class="fwsmain">
<div class="fwsside side-text"><span>Tinutul Neamtului</span><p class="text">Pentru cei care au fost prima data, tinutul Neamtului a devenit locul in care te intorci cu bucurie. Platoul cu preparate moldovenesti de la Hanul Ancutei, drumetiile pe Ceahlau, fotografiile de la Barajul Bicaz, viata de noapte din Piatra Neamt, zimbrii, cetatea Neamtului, manastiri din top 10 din Romania, Muzeul de masti de la Tincabesti sau casa memoriala a lui Creanga, sunt doar cateva dintre atractiile memorabile din aceasta zona. Si ai cel putin cinci evenimente de traditie pe care nu trebuie sa le ratezi.</p></div>

<div class="fwsside">
<div class="fwsside-flex1">

<div class="fwsitem"><div class="hoverbg"><span>Case memoriale</span></div></div>
<div class="fwsitem"><div class="hoverbg"><span>Turnul lui Ștefan</span></div></div>
<div class="fwsitem"><div class="hoverbg"><span>Orașul de sus</span></div></div>
<div class="fwsitem"><div class="hoverbg"><span>Hai la ski</span></div></div>
<div class="fwsitem fullw"><div class="hoverbg"><span>Trebuie să vezi</span></div></div>
  </div></div>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.fwsmain{
width: 100%;
display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;}

.fwsside {
height: 100%;
width: 50%;}

.side-text{
margin:auto;
padding:0 20px;}

.fwsside-flex1{
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
display:flex;
flex-shrink:1;
flex-grow:1;
flex-wrap:wrap;}

.fwsside-flex1 .fwsitem {
width:50%;
text-align: center;
background-size:cover;
}
.fullw{
width:100% !important;}

.hoverbg:hover {
background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}
.fwsside-flex1 .fwsitem:nth-child(1) {
background-image: url('http://descoperanordest.ro/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/calistrat-hogas.jpg');
}
.fwsside-flex1 .fwsitem:nth-child(2) {
background-image: url('http://descoperanordest.ro/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/clopotnita-turn-pnt.jpg');
}
.fwsside-flex1 .fwsitem:nth-child(3) {
background-image: url('http://descoperanordest.ro/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/telegondola.jpg');
}
.fwsside-flex1 .fwsitem:nth-child(4) {
background-image: url('http://descoperanordest.ro/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/ski.jpg');
}
.fwsside-flex1 .fwsitem:nth-child(5) {
background-image: url('http://descoperanordest.ro/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/cucuteni.jpg');
}

.fwsside-flex1 span {
line-height:33.3vh;
margin:auto;
    font-size: 33px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #fff;}
```

Comment: The one thing you're missing is a CSS declaration for what to do with "a" tags.  Without that, CSS will default to whatever is there.  Which could be anything.  And it could cause all sorts of troubles.

Comment: Can you update your jsfiddle to include your <a> tag additions ?

Comment: Where are you adding `<a />` tags ("for every box" is vague)? and "messes everything up" is also very vague, could you clarify?

Comment: I have updated the <a> tag additions. Sorry about that. All of them are supposed to be equal squares. This is how it is supposed too look http://oi66.tinypic.com/iykcc5.jpg https://jsfiddle.net/983wga5c/7/

Comment: Where exactly have you updated? There are no <a> tags in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have to move your `class="fwsitem"` to your newly added `<a>` tags because they are now your flexbox container's (`.fwsside-flex1`) children.

Here is a updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/983wga5c/8/).

Comment: @MateiB you can probably safely remove the extra `div` you moved the `fwsitem` from also if you want fyi